# ¿Como hacer un select2 personalizado como aparece en la API del mismo plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

No encuentro como personalizar mi `select2` como lo hacen en la API. ([aqui el enlace](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)).

Busco en todos lados y en la misma API del pligin no especifican nada de como hacerlo. Aclaro que lo hago en mi sistema pero de manera sencilla.

Aca el codigo:

```
$('#crear_lineas_de_produccion').select2({
    placeholder: "Nombre",
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'procesos/select/getLineasdeProduccion',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page || 1, //page number
            }
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data.results,
                pagination: {
                    more: data.pagination.more,
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

**Actualización 1:**
El resultado que me arroja es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quisiera algo como en la documentación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer algo así para colocar las descripciones de los lotes mejor ordenados y no separados por un "/", es lo único que se me ocurrió.

Comment: ¿Da error? ¿Qué error? Siempre conviene comentar el resultado de lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: @A.Cedano No da error, pero lo que quiero es personalizarlo como lo hacen en la documentación del mismo.

Comment: Si explicas lo que quiere decir _personalizarlo_ creo que será más fácil ayudarte, así como si compartes el trozo de html que va ligado a tu jQuery. No estamos, como tú, frente a tu monitor, ni podemos adivinar lo que quieres. :) Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya coloque unos screenshot de lo que deseo personalizar.

Comment: Los screen shots serán muy fáciles de hacer, pero poco útiles a la hora de responder: 1º porque si el otro está desde un móvil no se ven, 2º porque no siempre explica lo que hay en la mente del usuario. Cuando puedas revisa por favor esto: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta Considero que si en la pregunta redactas con palabras lo que quieres hacer sería más útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya queda de nuestra creatividad crear los `select`, yo lo manejo de la siguiente manera (en el jSon):

> id para el value del select

> text para el texto que se mostrara al estar el seleccionado el select

> descripción u otras columnas del json que deseen agregar las utilizo como estilos para el select

```js
var data = [
    {"id":1,"text":"Solidos","descripcion":"Fabricación de productos Solidos"},
    {"id":2,"text":"Líquidos Esteriles","descripcion":"Fabricación de productos liquidos que requieren un tratado mas delicado"},{"id":3,"text":"Líquidos No Esteriles","descripcion":"Fabricación de productos liquidos que requieren un tratado no tan delicado"}];


    $("select").select2({
      data: data,
             escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
             templateResult: formatData,
             templateSelection: formatDataSelection
    });

           function formatData (data) {
            if (data.loading) return data.text;
          var markup = '<div clas="col-sm-12"><b>' + data.text + '</b></div>';
           markup += '<div clas="col-sm-12"><span class="fa fa-info"></span> <small>' + data.descripcion + '</small></div>';
               //console.debug(data);
               //markup = "<h1>" + data.text + "</h1>" + "<p>" + data.text + "</p>";
               return markup;
            }

            function formatDataSelection (data) {
               return data.text;
            }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <select style="width: 100%"></select>
```